# Mailchimp add name

Tags: php, email, mailchimp, subscribe

i'm trying to add a new user to my list on mailchimp (email, first name and last name). But i've could not, any help would be apreciated.

my variables:

```
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
$arr = explode(' ',trim($nombre));
```

included Mailchimp api v2.0

```
include('Path/to/Mailchimp.php');

$api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx"; 
$list_id = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp( $api_key );
$Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists( $Mailchimp );
```

then, after some steps i try to subscribe a new user to my list:

```
try {
    $subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe( $list_id, array( 'email' => $email)); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

but, when i try to change to:

```
$subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe( $list_id, array( 'email' => $email, 'FNAME'=>'Test', 'LNAME'=>'Account' ));
```

Nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried logging $e to see if there was an exception?

Comment: Make sure your API key is from an account with manager, admin, or owner premissions.

Comment: yes, i did, but didn´t output anything.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Yotam, I'm admin, i'm sure. I actually can add users this way but i want to add the user's name as well

Comment: @Fred-ii- i did, nothing shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved it! by adding the missing parameters

```
try {
$merge_vars = array("FNAME"=>$arr[0],"LNAME"=>$arr[1],);
$double_optin = FALSE;
        $subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe( $list_id, array( 'email' => $email), $merge_vars,'html',$double_optin ); 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e;
    }
```

Comment: Another happy ending ;-)